# Select Mysql with multiple greater and lower values

Tags: php, mysql, select

i am in need of a search query based on 6 values from 3 columns day, month, year, right now i have got it some how working only for month and year but i can not get the day to perform correctly.

for example if some one wants to search from day, month year to day month year.
my current query

```
    //From
    list($fy,$fm,$fd)   = explode ('-', 2013-2-20);
    //to
    list($ty,$tm,$td)   = explode ('-', 2014-9-1);

    $add = " AND 
            ( month >= '".$fm."'
            AND year >='".$fy."') AND ( 
            month <= '".$tm."' 
            AND year <=   '".$ty."'
            ) ";
```

as you can see the day is not included, your time is much appreciated.

Comment: What columns are in your table, to me it looks like other than using some `Date` datatype you have the actual `day` (mabye), `month`, and `year` columns (which I don't really recommend doing)?

Comment: Your data design is wrong. A date is a single value and should not be split across 3 attributes. You can fudge a solution by casting the concatenated attributes back to a date, but the performance will suck.

Comment: Its a database designed by some one else and a part of a large project which i can't change, the project is for non-english country and their date and time system functions differently.
@SpencerWieczorek yes there is day, month, year columns in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Going on with what you have. You would just add `day` in the same way you added `month` and `year`:

```
...
$add = " AND 
        ( month >= '".$fm."'
        AND year >='".$fy."'
        AND day >='".$fd."') AND ( 
        month <= '".$tm."' 
        AND year <=   '".$ty."'
        AND day <=   '".$td."'
        ) ";
...
```

Since all the items are independent of each other, this works of the literal values are higher/lower in each item. Which is probably not what you want. You will need to convert the strings `'2013-2-20'` into DATE and then use those. This can be done with [`str_to_date()`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-str_to_date-function.php). So for example `str_to_date('2013-2-20','%Y-%m-%d')`.

**Notice:** I'm aware that you cannot change the database but for future references it's a good idea to have a single [DATE datatype](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) for your database. It's not good design to separate them into separates things such as *day*, *month*, and *year*. As with using the DATE datatype it can easily find lower and higher dates by simply comparing the dates (along with date functions using dates can be used):

```
dateObj1 >= dateObj2 // dateObj1 is at a later date than dateObj2
```

Comment: I have tried that method already, and it does only work if from day is lower then to day!

Comment: @codedudey Because they are completely independent from each other, which is why it's a good idea to convert them into a Date datatype.

Comment: i will try to convince them into allowing me to change the system, thank you.